# How to change the class on one div while hovering over another div with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to change the class of one div while hovering over another div using AngularJS directives. Here is what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/E8nM5/38/

HMTL

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-app>
   <div ng-class="my-class">This div will change class when one hovers over bottom DIV </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="hover-div" ng-mouseenter="my-class = 'highlight'" ng-mouseleave="my-class = 'lowlight'">HOVER OVER ME TO CHANGE THE UPPER DIV's CLASS</div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.highlight {
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

div.lowlight {
    padding: 10px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

div.hover-div {
    padding: 10px;
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
```

JS

```
function Ctrl($scope){
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `my-class` to `myclass` (i.e. the dash causes problem).

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-app>
    <div ng-class="myclass">This div will change class when one hovers over bottom DIV </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="hover-div" ng-mouseenter="myclass = 'highlight'" ng-mouseleave="myclass = 'lowlight'">HOVER OVER ME TO CHANGE THE UPPER DIV's CLASS</div>    
</div>
```

**Updated:** the reason `my-class` isn't allowed in the expression is because AngularJS treats the dash as minus symbol and tries to parse it that way. Apparently, it can't parse the statement `my - class = 'highlight'`. Unfortunately, after reading AngularJS parser code, I can't find a way to "help" it distinguish between dash and minus.

Comment: There is no reason to differentiate between the two. `my-class` is an invalid Javascript variable name. That's it. One should understand that `myclass` is a Javascript variable and not a CSS Class. So the naming rules to be followed if of JS and not CSS.

Comment: @siddhant3s one can assign `$scope['my-class'] = ...`, which is both valid JS and AngularJS. So the OP asked a perfectly reasonable question and it would certainly be helpful if AngularJS can support that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the hyphen from my-class so it will work properly in your Controller. Other than that it looks like you have it mostly done. Here's a little snippet - I also added it as text in the div so you can see it change

### Your HTML File:

```
<div class="{{myClass}}"> {{myClass}} </div>
    
     <div class="hover" style="height:50px; width:50px; border:1px solid black;" ng-mouseleave="myClass='test'" ng-mouseenter="myClass='hola'"> </div>
```

### Controller

```
function Ctrl($scope){
    $scope.myClass="test";
}
```