# How to highlight the table row on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this table:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">

  <table class="table table-bordered ">  
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Sushi Roll 
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'fish'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
          Fish Type 
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish">
        <td>{{ roll.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ roll.fish }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
```

Here is controller:

```
angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.searchFish   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

  // create the list of sushi rolls 
  $scope.sushi = [
    { name: 'Cali Roll', fish: 'Crab' },
    { name: 'Philly', fish: 'Tuna' },
    { name: 'Tiger', fish: 'Eel' },
    { name: 'Rainbow', fish: 'Variety' }
  ];

});
```

Here is [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/d8atdw0t/304/).

I want to highlight the border of table row on mouse hover using `ng-mouseover` directive.

How can I implement it?

Comment: why do you prefer `ng-mouseover` for an effect you can achieve with css only?

Comment: have you heard of css `:hover` selector?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal, yes I heard ,but I need to use ng-mouseover

Comment: @Michael in that case I am not the right guy to answer this question as I have near to zero experience with angular

Comment: @Michael Why do you NEED to use ng-mouseover? In my opinion, that is clearly a concern for CSS. Everything else is much more unreadable and complicated.

Answer (score 9):

HTML:

```
<table class="table-hover">
```

CSS:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

And if else you want is to make the *tr* selectable:

HTML:

```
<tr ng-click="doSomething()">
```

CSS:

```
tr[ng-click] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[View JSFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/pdorgambide/vb7tmLp4/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Angular, so this may be the incorrect way to do this, but this seems to work on your fiddle ...

change the row to

```
<tr ng-class="rollClass" ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish" ng-mouseenter="rollClass = 'highlight'" ng-mouseleave="rollClass = ''">
```

and add the css class

```
.highlight {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

The idea comes from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390473/how-to-change-the-class-on-one-div-while-hovering-over-another-div-with-angularj)

Answer (score 2):

you can apply class on mouse over  like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/uuws8hbv/

```
<tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish track by $index" ng-mouseover="rowselected($index)" 
  ng-class="{selected : $index == rowNumber}"
```

in the controller add function.

```
$scope.rowselected = function(row)
{
   $scope.rowNumber = row;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for Angular, should be accepted